# how to use jquery in amember pro

Tags: php, jquery, amember

i want to add script for redirect purpose. in

```
/amember/library/Am/Paysystem/Abstract.php in thanksaction function
```

i am using following code

```
$response->addScript()
                ->setScript(<<<CUT
jQuery(function($){

window.location.href ="http://www.google.com/";
});
CUT
);
```

But i am getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Am_Mvc_Response::addScript() in    /amemberroot/library/Am/Paysystem/Abstract.php
```

do anyone know what could be the issue?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Am_Mvc_Response** class has not such methods as **addScript**. aMember has open source code and you always can check class declarations. To do redirect just use the following code:

```
Am_Mvc_Response::redirectLocation("http://www.google.com/");
```